# Rename Schema having virtual tables in SAP HANA

Tags: hana

I am facing the below error while renaming the schema in HANA2,

```
SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: Cannot rename virtual table VT_EMP_EMPLOYMENT_INFO
```

It is successfully renamed if the schema is not having virtual tables,
The above issue is coming only when there are virtual tables in Schema, Below is the SQL script I'm using

```
RENAME SCHEMA "MYSCHEMA" TO "RENAMESCHEMA"
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming virtual tables (and thus renaming a schema that includes virtual tables) is apparently not supported.

I haven't found any documentation about this, but the behavior is what's present with the current HANA Express Edition 2 SPS 04.

The only option I see to effectively rename the schema including virtual tables is to use the export/import method with `RENAME SCHEMA` option.